# Marshmallow - Add parameter to include children entities

Tags: python, database-schema, marshmallow

I have a database model called Store with relationship with Products. Have also defined a StoreSchema that is working just fine. I can retrieve a Store and its Products when using the  dump method.

Now, I don't want to aways bring the products but have an option for it, passing some kind of parameter, but can't find a simple solution for that. Would I need to create a second StoreSchema that don't include the products or I can change it in a way to cover both behaviours?

Here is the current code

```
from marshmallow import fields

from app import db, ma
from app.models.product import ProductSchema


class Store(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "stores"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    public_id = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    affiliate_code = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.CHAR(2), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    products = db.relationship("Product", backref="store", lazy='dynamic')

    def serialize(self):
        return StoreSchema().dump(self)


class StoreSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    products = fields.List(fields.Nested(ProductSchema, exclude=['id']))
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['id']
        model = Store
        load_instance = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exlude products at instantiation:

```py
schema = StoreSchema(exclude=("products", ))
```

The list passed here is OR-ed with the `exclude` list passed as `Meta` attribute so you don't have to repeat "id".